# Script to generate data, SQL oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm trying to build a script that insert random datas into my table.

My actual script looks like that :

```
INSERT INTO Utilisateurs (id_utilisateur, Uti_nom, Uti_prenom, Uti_role, Uti_mdp, Uti_Statut)
SELECT
  -- here to input the id (number that increment each time)
  dbms_random.string('A', trunc(dbms_random.value(5, 50))), -- data for uti_nom
  dbms_random.string('A', trunc(dbms_random.value(5, 100))), -- data for uti_prenom
  -- randomly get 'Administrateur' or 'Utilisateur'
  dbms_random.string('X', 10), -- data for uti_mdp
  trunc(dbms_random.value(0, 1)) -- data for uti_status
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 100;
```

So if someone can help me to get the both comment line...

There's a sample, but what i really need it's the `ID` that increments and `Uti_role` (Administrateur/Utilisateur) the others fields can be generated and looks like "dsjhadakj"

```
id_utilisateur   Uti_nom   Uti_prenom    Uti_role        Uti_mdp      Uti_Statut
d--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
   1             Elche        Marco    Administrateur  Haj432Hgn         1
   2             Babo         Jules    Utilisateur     Haj432Hgn         0          
   3             Ghale        Alex     Administrateur  Haj432Hgn         1
```

Comment: Can you please post your table definition and some sample results of your inner query?

Comment: Please explain `-- here a random to get 'Administrateur' or 'Utilisateur'`.  Do you mean that you want to randomly get one of these two strings?

Comment: @PM77-1 Updated, and yes that what i'm trying to explain here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For self-incremental ID you can use `LEVEL`
2. For `uti_role` something like this:

   `CASE WHEN dbms_random.value(0, 1) > 0.5 THEN 'Administrateur' ELSE 'Utilisateur' END`

Here's **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/11003)** for just the `SELECT` part.

Comment: Thank you ! I'll try it tomorrow and probably validate your answer ! Just another ask, if i've more than only 2 options like : administrateur, utilisateur and invité how can i do it ?

Comment: Have you looked at the demo (`SQL Fiddle`)? It runs on `11g` but should be fine for `10g` as well.

Comment: Yes i've looked and wow that's awesome , but i don't have oracle now.

Comment: Ok i've found something [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php) for multiple condition